# Unable to register DbConnection with Unity and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, dbcontext

I am not at all sure what the underlying problem is that is causing this exception.

I am using ASP.NET MVC, with Unity.Mvc, and Entity Framework 6. I have the following code to register my repositories:

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        // TODO: Register your types here
        // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Customer>, GenericRepository<Customer>>();
        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Product>, GenericRepository<Product>>();
        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Order>, GenericRepository<Order>>();
        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<OrderItem>, GenericRepository<OrderItem>>();
        container.RegisterType<IGenericRepository<Supplier>, GenericRepository<Supplier>>();
    }
```

And then in a controller I have:

```
public class IndexController : Controller
{
    public IndexController(IGenericRepository<Customer> testGenericRepository)
    {
        var result = testGenericRepository.SelectAll();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the repository has the following code:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            if (dbContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbContext));
            }

            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
        {
            return _dbSet.AsEnumerable<T>();
        }
    }
```

The problem that I'm having is that if I have a breakpoint in the "RegisterTypes" method, I can see that the container is definitely getting all the repositories registered, but a breakpoint in the constructor of the repositories never gets hit.

So I think that the fact that the breakpoint does not get hit, and I have not registered a "System.Data.Common.DbConnection" means that the `DbContext` that the repository uses never gets set.

I can't find any useful information about how to use "System.Data.Common.DbConnection" with Unity and the DbContext from Entity Framework.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add to your `RegisterTypes` how to build your `DbContext`, and probably with which lifetime.

If you have your own class (say `CustomContext`) inheriting from `DbContext`, register it. Supposing your default lifetime is adequate:

```cs
container.RegisterType<DBContext, CustomContext>();
```

If you use directly `DbContext`, instruct Unity which constructor it should use. By example, supposing your connection string is named `appConnectionString`:

```cs
container.RegisterType<DBContext>(
    new InjectionConstructor("name=appConnectionString"));
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I am surprised this was not mentioned more in the documentation.

Comment: Well, when registering a type, you should check its dependencies and ensure they are registered too. Otherwise Unity will try what it can to resolve those dependencies and will likely fail.