# Register EF Core in Prism in full .NET Framework

Tags: c#, prism, unity-container, .net-framework-version, ef-core-2.2

I want to use EF.Core 2.2.6 in a .Net Framework (4.6.2) project. I have created a separate project for the database.

I want to register the `DbContext` in the main project using dependency injection over the Prism framework (Unity).

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=CustomerDB.db");
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<DbContext, CrossSettingContext>();
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<DbContext>(new InjectionConstructor(optionsBuilder));
```

The database context:

```
public  class CrossSettingContext : DbContext
{
    private static Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> onConfigure;
    #pragma warning restore 649

    public CrossSettingContext(DbContextOptions<CrossSettingContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
        onConfigure?.Invoke(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Setting>().Map();
    }
}
```

I get the following exception. The question is if I am using the right approach for registering EF Core.

> System.InvalidOperationException: "No member matching data has been found.
>
> Error in:  RegisterType(Invoke.Constructor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder`1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext]))

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974965/unable-to-register-dbconnection-with-unity-and-entity-framework) -> but I need EF Core 2.2.6 and not Entity Framework 6.0

Comment: i dont think you can use DotNetCore types in the old dot net projects. You would have to compile it first and then use the compiled lib.

Comment: @Charles: EF Core 2.2.6 is full Compatible with Net Framework.  The Database Lib is an Net.Standard Project (2.0)

Comment: In your main project, ensure that the type `DbContext` type resolves as you expect.  And why are you using the base DbContext type instead of your application's DbContext subtype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from Haukinger is partially correct, but missing quite a bit of important information.

What you will want to do something like:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CrossSettingContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite( @"Data Source=CustomerDB.db" );
```

However you do not need anything Container Specific AT ALL here. All you really need is:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

You do not actually need to register the `CrossSettingContext` if you want a new instance each time it's resolved. Though you could do the following if you want a singleton:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<CrossSettingContext>();
```

When you want to use it you can just inject the context in your ViewModel/Services like:

```
public class ViewAViewModel
{
    public ViewAViewModel(CrossSettingContext context)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```